# Is there htaccess rule to redirect two same url with different parameter on the other same url with other parameter?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have two URLs '/cover-letters/abcd/' and '/cover-letters/abcd/amp' and want to redirect it to '/cover-letter/examples/maintenance/xyz' and '/cover-letter/examples/maintenance/xyz/amp' respectively.

Can it be done by a single htaccess 301 redirect rule? Or is there any other way to do it?

I have tried all the solutions given on StackOverflow. Please suggest the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing it in WordPress/PHP is going to give you greater flexibility and control, in general, but you have to wait for a bunch of PHP code to execute fist, which may not be good/ideal. So if it can be avoided, the .htaccess file is best for that. Your question was specially about if you could do it in .htaccess, so here is how you do that:

```
RedirectMatch 301 (/?)cover-letters/abcd(/?)([^/]*) $1cover-letter/examples/maintenance/xyz$2$3
```

However that are also some reason/scenarios where you may not want to or cannot use the .htaccess. A little off topic, but worth noting for others.

---

Since you tagged WordPress in your question you can also install https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/ . It's a very easy to use, well done plugin for redirections. I use it all the time and highly recommend it.

---

**Edit for question in the comments**

In order to test against query strings you need to use the `mod_rewrite` module. The `mod_alias` modules (used in the original answer) does not support query string lookups. You need to do the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(abcd)$
RewriteRule ^(.*?)(/?)$ $1/%0 [R=301,QSD,L]
```

Comment: **RedirectMatch 301 (/?)cover-letters/abcd(/?)([^/]*) cover-letter/examples/maintenance/xyz** This rule worked too. What was the use of "$2$3"?

Comment: For regex items wrapped in parens `(` and `)` are saved to a "capture group". Those capture groups get saved incrementally starting at `1` prefixed with `$`. So `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, etc. What I was saying was replace `cover-letters/abcd` with `cover-letter/examples/maintenance/xyz` and keep all the stuff around it intact (like `amp` in your example). There are numerous ways to attack this, but based on your question I inferred this as being the most likely way for what you wanted. There are many possible answers, the most accurate is the one that satisfies the most edge cases correctly.

Comment: `RedirectMatch 301 (/?)cover-letters/abcd(/?)([^/]*) $1cover-letter/examples/maintenance/xyz$2$3` is working fine if I want to redirect `cover-letters?abcd` or `cover-letters/?abcd` to `cover-letters/abcd`, whant changes I need to de? @PhilF

Comment: I've updated the answer, but you can't use mod_alias for query strings. So it's a multi-line answer